# Is this RxJs pipe() chain understanding correct?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on an Angular project involving RxJS and I have some doubts about how exactly works this piece of code made by someone else (it works fine). I am not so into RxJS and I am struggling with it.

Basically this code is used to perform search. Into the front end there is a search form field where the user insert words that will be searched into a collection of products.

So in my HTML page I have something like this:

```
<input class="mx-2" type="search" placeholder="Cerca qui" [formControl]="filter">
```

Then in my TypeScript code I have this definition:

```
filter = new FormControl('');
```

Since the user will insert characters one by one into the previous input form it will listen into the **ngOnInit()** for changes of the **filter** variable value, in this way:

```
this.filter.valueChanges
.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  debounceTime(300),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  map((t) => (typeof t === 'number' ? t.toString() : t)),
  tap((text) =>
    !!wineList
      ? this.listWines$.next(this.search(text, wineList))
      : null
  )
)
.subscribe();
```

And here I am finding some difficulties trying to understand how exactly works the previous code section. This is my interpretation, please correct me if I am doing wrong asssertion:

The **valueChanges** property of the **filter** FormControl is an **Observable** that emit a new value each time that something change on the controll (basically when the user insert a new chartacter or delete a character from the search string). So this event is subscribed in order to detect a change. So the operation defined into the RxJS **pipe()** operator are executed one by one (as a chain of operations) each time that a new characted is added\deleted into the input form.

And here the behavior of this chain:

First of all **startWith('')** add a white space in front of the new searched char. Itself emit a new Observable object representing this "new" inserted char. This new Observable will be processed by the next step of the chain.

The next step of the chain is the **debounceTime(300)** that is simply used to emit an Observable resenting the inserted string value (toward the next chain step) after 300 ms. I suppose that this is done in order to avoid performance drops during any searches made by multiple users.

then the next step in the chain is **takeUntil(this.destroy$)** emit the event (representing my searched string) after that this **this.destroy$** Observable object emit (I don't kwno why...but it is not so important I think)

Them the next step in the chain is the crucial point:

```
map((t) => (typeof t === 'number' ? t.toString() : t)),
```

Basically **map()** RxJS operator take a function that changes the value of my String and emit a new Observable object representing the new char. In this case if the char is a number it is converted into a string.

Finnally the **tap()** operator is used to perform a side effect, in this case the side effect is to perform a new search() operation each time that a new character is added into the search form field. Itself emit a new Observable object containing the list of retrieved products.

Is it my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(

  // start the stream by emitting an empty string.
  // this is only done once - not per emitted value.
  // the reasoning behind this, is that your pipeline expects strings or such
  // and to avoid errors, its initialized with an empty string as its first emit.
  startWith(''),

  // debounce the values that are being emitted.
  // this is used to prevent doing some expensive logic, for every key press (value change)
  // so this actually defers emissions by 300 milliseconds BEFORE actually "emitting" the last value.
  debounceTime(300),
  
  // every time you subscribe, you need to unsubscribe.
  // in order to avoid unsubscribing each and every subscription
  // we usually create a local subject, name it "destory" or something,
  // `destroy = new Subject<any>()`
  // and have it emit a value when component destroys
  // `ngOnDestroy() { this.destroy.next(); }`
  // then use the takeUntil operator on every stream to unsubscribe itself when the destroy subject emits
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),

  // if user enters a number, cast to string, else, keep it as is
  map((t) => (typeof t === 'number' ? t.toString() : t)),

  // tap is similar to placing the logic inside the "next" block.
  // it's usually used to either have side-effects, or, when you wish not to subscribe manually
  // which is why here, this is actually quite redundant and belongs to the .subscribe callback which is empty for some reason.
  tap((text) =>
    !!wineList
      ? this.listWines$.next(this.search(text, wineList))
      : null
  )
)
.subscribe();
```